# How can I change the following static linked program into dynamic linked program?

Tags: c++, linker, glibc, dynamic-linking, embedded-v8

I have already figure out how to staticly link v8 with my own GLIBC/STDC++.

```
$(GCC_ROOT)/bin/g++ samples/bench.cpp -o bench -isystem$(GLIBC_ROOT)/include/ -I. -Iinclude -isystem$(GLIBC) -nodefaultlibs  -DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS -static $(V8_OBJ)/libv8_monolith.a -Wl,--start-group $(GCC_ROOT)/lib64/libstdc++.a  $(GLIBC_ROOT)/lib/libpthread.a $(GLIBC_ROOT)/lib/libdl.a $(GLIBC_ROOT)/lib/libm.a $(GLIBC_ROOT)/lib/librt.a $(GCC_GCC)/libgcc.a $(GCC_GCC)/libgcc_eh.a $(GCC_GCC)/libcommon.a $(GLIBC_ROOT)/lib/libc.a -Wl,--end-group
```

However, I find it not good to link all stuff staticly, and I want to GLIBC/STDC++ dynamicly, and my strategy is:

1. For all .a which is staticly linked, I use `-Wl,-rpath=` to specify its path.
2. For those .a which has no corresponding .so, such as libgcc.a, I still link them staticly.

So I write the following command

```
$(GCC_ROOT)/bin/g++ samples/bench.cpp -isystem$(GLIBC_ROOT)/include/ -I. -Iinclude -isystem$(GLIBC_ROOT)/ -o bench_dyn -nodefaultlibs  -DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS -Wl,--start-group $(V8_OBJ)/libv8_monolith.a  -Wl,-rpath=$(GCC_ROOT)/lib64/ $(GCC_GCC)/libgcc.a $(GCC_GCC)/libgcc_eh.a $(GCC_GCC)/libcommon.a -Wl,-rpath=$(GLIBC_ROOT)/lib -Wl,--end-group
```

However, this strategy won't work, because lots of symbols are not found, such as

1. `pthread_mutex_*`
2. `std::ostream::operator<<(int)`

I think these are all GLIBC/STDC++ symbols, and I linked them dynamicly, so they should not remain undefined?

What's wrong here?

Comment: Context: [Why pthread_rwlock_t's ABI differs a lot among versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65230865/why-pthread-rwlock-ts-abi-differs-a-lot-among-versions/65235265#65235265).

Comment: To statically link Glibc on a system that defaults to dynamic linking, you have to jump through several hoops that are simply unnecessary with dynamic linking.  I suggest rewriting your link command from scratch instead of trying to convert it from the static version.

Comment: Also, shared and static libraries often mix poorly.  I strongly recommend that all reusable libraries be built as shared libraries on systems that use shared libraries.